# Avoid browser addons to mess with code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, browser-extension

Since iv been working with javascript and ajax services I have noticed that there are some browser plugins that has tendency to mess with the contense of the code and values stored for services and scripts. Addons like OpenScape and Skype for example can do some messing with phone numbers if any are found. And this can mess up quiet a bit when it comes to scripts and services.

This can be noticed like for example, if you have a service-script on a page and you have a phone number on the page, OpenScape for example goes in to the code and modify the phone number and what should happened when now can click it. This can allso mess up the service variables because if you call these the values wont exist any more and be 'null'. Not OK.

**Question:**
Is there some way to avoid browser addons influence like this to make sure plugins dont mess with webpage contense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. As simple as that.